# GitHub action CI check for npm test keep running non stop

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, github-actions, git-workflow

I have worked with `github actions` before while setting up `github-workflow`, but this is the first time I'm including action/job for `npm test`.

I have configured it to run the actions on pull request to develop branch as usual... but the tests never finish running in the github action jobs. I've been googling but can't seem to find a relevant solution.

**Github pull-request screenshot 1**
[image: github-action-still-running]

**Github pull-request screenshot 2**
[image: github-action-still-running-jobs]

I'm using `nodejs` and the test is written with `jasmine`. I don't know if it has anything to do with my settings or test configuration which I set up myself, so I've also included some relevant code/files below just in case.

**.github/workflows/node.js.yml**

```
# This workflow will do a clean install of node dependencies, build the source code and run tests across different versions of node
# For more information see: https://help.github.com/actions/language-and-framework-guides/using-nodejs-with-github-actions

name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main, develop ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main, develop ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [10.x, 12.x, 14.x, 15.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - run: npm ci
    - run: npm run build --if-present
    - run: npm test
```

The `node.js.yml` file above☝is already in the `develop branch`.

**package.json**

```
{
  //scripts

  "scripts": {
    "prestart": "node -r esm src/startMessage.js",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel lint:watch",
    "lint": "esw src --color",
    "lint:watch": "npm run lint -- --watch",
    "test": "nodemon --exec babel-node spec/run.js"
  },
  
//dependencies

  "dependencies": {
    "arg": "^5.0.0",
    "chalk": "^4.1.0",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "execa": "^5.0.0",
    "inquirer": "^8.0.0",
    "listr": "^0.14.3",
    "ncp": "^2.0.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "pkg-install": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "eslint": "^7.21.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-watch": "^7.0.0"
    "eslint-watch": "^7.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^3.6.4",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

**src/cli.js**

```
export let cli = (args) => {
  console.log(args);
}
```

**spec/cli.spec.js**

```
import { cli as cli } from '../src/cli';

describe('cli function', () => {

  it('should return undefined', () => {
    let test = cli();
    expect(test).toBeUndefined();
  });
});
```

**spec/run.js**

```
import Jasmine from 'jasmine';

const jasmine = new Jasmine();
jasmine.loadConfigFile('spec/support/jasmine.json');

jasmine.execute();
```

**spec/support/jasmine.json**

```
{
  "spec_dir": "spec",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*[sS]pec.js"
  ],
  "helpers": [
    "helpers/**/*.js"
  ],
  "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
  "random": true
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "env"
  ]
}
```

The test works fine locally when I run `npm test` in my terminal. I need help with the github action/workflow on push or pull request (so that I can merge the feature branch which contains the test into the development branch):

- What is making the test run non-stop in the GitHub action?
- How can I get the github action checks to pass and run successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I've not had the chance to look at your GitHub repo, from what you've posted here, one solution I'll propose is to:

1. have dev-test as part of your script that will run `nodemon --exec babel-node spec/run.js` in your package.json configuration
2. change the test script of your package.json to `babel-node spec/run.js`.

This will ensure that the tests will be run only once when a change is pushed. SO, when working locally, you can use `npm run dev-test` to keep the test on for the entire period you are making changes locally.

Comment: Separating the CI test command from that of dev worked like charm, thank you!

Comment: I'm not able to edit your answer. Please help edit your answer well: Remove node --exec from no. 2 i.e. just babel-node spec/run.js and add run to the test command i.e. npm run dev-test.

Comment: Looks good . Thank you! So that I can use: `npm test` command in development, I left test script in the package.json as `nodemon --exec babel-node spec/run.js` . Then changed the dev-test to CI-test: `babel-node spec/run.js`. Then used `npm run CI-test` in the node.js.yml file. I finally get the gist, automating with nodemon was the issue. Thanks again.

Comment: ho do i provide env variable